# I would like to export a video with a transparent background so that it doesn't get laggy

Tags: rendering

I can export the file with a transparent background, but when I play it using VLC media player, it is very choppy. I would like to make it play smoothly.

I'm currently rendering with the following settings

Transparent: ✓
Color: RGBA
Quicktime, OT rle / QT Animation
[image]

I've tried setting the Keyframe Interval to 0 and exporting it, but it didn't smooth out.

What is the problem with this?

This is my laggy movie.(This is famous File Transfer Service)
https://4.gigafile.nu/0223-d6710b3301cca03e2eaa83d962a32517e
you can download from this button.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not solve it by using Quicktime. **Realtime** compression and **64 render samples** gave me half-smooth half choppy render, but it's not enough. There may be a bug in the encoder.

However, it worked fine with **PNG**, **RGBA**, **%0 compression**. And, you have more control over your video when you render it as an image sequence.

You can import **PNG sequence** to Blender and export it again as a video file format, or you can use other video editing softwares to give its final shape.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
And thank you so much polite answer.
Actually I tried to export as PNG then export it again as .mov or .avi something.
But nothing changed...
Can you tell me what Output Properties you used to export the PNG as a video?
I usually output PNGs as mp4, so I know how to do it, but mp4 is a codec that doesn't support background transparency, so I need to output it as mov or avi, and I'm surprised how hard it is...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I've changed the Keyframe Interval to 0. It did not work in Quicktime but worked in PNG for me. Also, I've done this in both Blender 3.0.1 and Blender 3.1.0 Beta for MacOS Arm versions. Which version of Blender are you using?
To export RGBA video, I usually import the video to After Effects, export to Adobe Media Encoder then Select "Quicktime -> Animation" with "alpha channel". This always work for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it correct to say that after exporting as PNG, I exported the mov file using Image Sequence with the keyframe interval set to 0, and it became smoother?

I've tried with 3.0.0 Alpha/ 3.0.0/3.0.1, but none of them worked.

I'm using Davinci Resolve, so I tried that too, but it didn't work because the background transparency turned green, so I'm thinking of completing it on Blender.
(I wish I could use Adobe, but...)

Comment: I've downloaded the Da Vinci and imported sequence to it. I had no problem like green background or whatsoever. With these settings, I got a clean render with alpha: Format: QuickTime, Codec: Apple ProRes, Type: Apple ProRes 444, Export Alpha: Checked.
It seems like the latest Da Vinci has a problem with image sequence imports. It does not detect the image sequence, so I've imported all the PNGs to media window. Then go to Preferences -> User -> Editing -> General Settings -> Standard Still Duration -> Frames: 1. I've done this because every PNG frame on the timeline is 5 seconds long.

Comment: Can you get clean exports with PNG settings right now? I've written the above comment as you are clean with PNG export. Please tell me if there is still a problem.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for testing to use DaVinci Resolve. I tried it but I use windows so I can not export as Apple ProRos..(Sorry I should mentioned it before...)
I got clean PNG by your settings. I keep try to find the solution. thank you.

Comment: I cannot use my Windows PC right now, so I cannot try it. But last week, I had clean alpha renders with the encoder I've mentioned above using Adobe Media Encoder. ProRes is not MacOS only encoder. I cannot check it right now, but Da Vinci probably has that encoder in Windows. Did you check it? It would be bad not to have that in the Windows version of Da Vinci. I was thinking about changing my workflow into Da Vinci.

Comment: I see. I don't know this way is best or not, but I found this video about how to export Apple ProRes in Windows. I use DaVinci Resolve Studio(need licence) so I could use this addon. I got ProRes video. but it still choppy. So I tried other codec AVI, that looks smooth for me. But I can not import that avi file to DaVinci Resolve. So I am trying to find the solution now. BTW, I recommend DaVinci Resolve to use as render. If you make video for YouTube or someting, I recommend Adobe.

Comment: As I mentioned  before, export the video in DaVinci Resolve, it looks wired green background. (you can see here https://www.dropbox.com/s/mu9b3jm1scxqq68/laggy.mov?dl=0) But when it import to DaVinci Resolve, it looks perfectly transparent. I can not understand what is happen... https://www.dropbox.com/s/c90olthkq5x3fcd/Screenshot%202022-02-16%20194030.png?dl=0
 (I used export setting→quicktime/Grass Valley)

Comment: Sorry for many reply. Finally I found the answer. I export in DaVinci Resolve as below setting. Frmat:QuickTime, Codec:DNxHR Type:DNxHR444 12-bit Export Alpha:✓
Thank you so much for so many anwer. I could not reach this way without you, Mr. Hazer.  Thank you so much!!!!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5bxqjghp0dirob/Screenshot%202022-02-16%20194544.png?dl=0

Comment: I've found another solution. Render your .blend file with these settings => File Format: FFmpeg Video | Encoding -> Container -> Quicktime | Video -> Video Codec -> PNG | Encoding Speed -> Realtime (this is for me to get quick result) | Color -> RGBA (this becomes available after you choose video codec as PNG) | Keyframe Interval -> 0. With this way, I got clean render and you don't have to work with another software. Can you check it?

Comment: Ohh Thank you!! I will check it soon! Thank you so much again...! ; ;

Comment: Your solution is perfectly worked!! this way is better! it save my time a lot. I've never seen polite people like you. I don't know how to say but... Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: Glad that it worked! Cheers ^^

Comment: Cheers!!! 